# VBA search a range for specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code in VBA where if the range/column contains the letter a and the cell, C5, is empty, then it will display an error message that the cell is empty. I've been testing this with numbers and have gotten that to work, but I'm having issues with doing it with text. I know the IsEmpty part of the code works because of what I've previously tried.

```
Sub Null_Test()
'
' Null_Test Macro
'

'
If (Range("A1:A20").Value = "a" And IsEmpty(Range("C5").Value) = True) Then
    MsgBox "A is Missing"
End If
End Sub
```

Along with this code, I've also tried:

```
If (Range("A1:A20").Find("a", LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True) And IsEmpty(Range("C5").Value) = True) Then
```

```
If (InStr(1, Range("A1:A20"), "a") And IsEmpty(Range("C5").Value) = True) Then
```

```
If (CountIf("A1:A20", "a") > 0) And IsEmpty(Range("C5").Value) = True) Then
```

None of these have worked.

Comment: You will need to use `worksheetfunction.CountIf("A1:A20", "a") > 0)`  `Range("A1:A20")` gives an array so string functions won't work as you'd expect.  Not sure why you're find wasn't.

Comment: Nothing from what you tried cannot work even with numbers. Can you show us the **working version** using numbers? I maybe did not understand very well what you try accomplishing and the code will clarify the issue...

Comment: This code with numbers works: `If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A20"), 3) > 0 And IsEmpty(Range("C4").Value) = True) Then
    MsgBox "3 is Missing" ` @FaneDuru

Comment: Range find returns the range found. You can set a variable to the range find, and then test it like `If Not 'variable' Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav this code worked great! Thank you so much! I was just missing the worksheetfunction and Range part.

Comment: Note that the `= True` is redundant.

Comment: Your code `If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A20"), 3) > 0 And IsEmpty(Range("C4").Value) = True)` is, at least, strange. Its part `IsEmpty(Range("C4").Value) = True)` will always return `False` and `MsgBox "3 is Missing"` will be returned (supposing that you correct the mentioned part `IsEmpty(Range("C4").Value)`) only if you use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A20"), 3) = 0`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop to check if in range, there is a single letter "a" on it

```
Sub Null_Test()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While Cells(i, 1).Cells <> ""
If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "a") And Range("C5").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "A is Missing"
  i = i + 1
  Else
  i = i + 1
  End If
Loop
End Sub
```

if you only want it to run through range("A1:A20") you can use a for loop

```
Sub Null_Test()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 20
If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "a") And Range("C5").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "A is Missing"
  End If
  Next
End Sub
```